# What happens to Console.WriteLine calls in Xamarin.iOS release builds?

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin, console

When developing iOS apps using XCode, you can use NSLog calls to write information to the console for debugging. In Xamarin.iOS, the same can be done with Console.WriteLine.

When running a release build of an app, without the debugger attached, these calls serve no purpose. So I've thought of excluding them with pre-processor directives:

```
#if DEBUG
Console.WriteLine("foo");
#endif
```

So that the calls don't even exist in the release build. I appreciate this may be micro-optimisation - but I'm curious if Xamairn already does this, making this unnecessary?

Comment: "In Xamarin.iOS, the same can be done with Console.WriteLine" Console.WriteLine sometimes calls NSLog.  Sometimes (like when you're running under the debugger) Console.WriteLine will do something else.  Thinking that NSLog and Console.WriteLine are the same will eventually cause you pain.

Comment: @JamesMoore could you elaborate on what "something else" is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Console` output is not removed in iOS release builds.

FYI: Xcode does not "automatically" remove `NSLog` or `print` from Obj-C/Swift "release" code either. (You typically define a single global preprocessor macro to remove them all, if desired...)

Your options are many... including:

- `DEBUG` preprocessor as you show in your question.
- Use `System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine`:

> Any calls to Debug.* will be removed by the compiler due to the [Conditional("DEBUG")] attribute being applied.

- Create your own "Logger" class as a wrapper to the `stdout` writers and `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` it
- Use `Fody` and re-weave the assemblies to remove/NOP/redirect the `WriteLine`

  - I do this to redirect the calls to in internal log and upon crash or user stat requests, forward this log to our crash reporting servers.
- etc, .....

Ref: Xamarin's [NSLogWriter](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/2edb2ae4f5bb371a7006731987717c01f8725420/src/Foundation/NSLogWriter.cs) Helper Class