# Xamarin Forms - iOS not processing correctly

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using the `CrossDownManager` plugin for Xamarin Forms 
[Here](https://github.com/SimonSimCity/Xamarin-CrossDownloadManager)
 When I run the method on Android it processes as expected.  On iOS `Debug.Writeline("Success!")`  isn't being hit like it was on Android.

Here is the code:

```
void ViewImage(string imageLink)
    {
        var downloadManager = CrossDownloadManager.Current;
        downloadManager.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new System.Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file =>
                    {
                        string path = DependencyService.Get<IImageSaver>().Save("YHTS" + DateTime.Today.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg");
                        Debug.WriteLine("Success!");
                             return path;
                         });

        try
        {
            var file = downloadManager.CreateDownloadFile(imageLink);
            Debug.WriteLine("file created");
            downloadManager.Start(file);
            Debug.WriteLine("downloadstarted");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why the that code block isn't processed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting issue as technically your code should work as expected. I've done a little digging and found a reply to a similar question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39195254/4486115)

> your options are many... including:
>
> DEBUG preprocessor as you show in your question.
>
> Use System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine: Any calls to Debug.* will be
>   removed by the compiler due to the [Conditional("DEBUG")] attribute
>   being applied.
>
> Create your own "Logger" class as a wrapper to the stdout writers and
>   [Conditional("DEBUG")] it
>
> Use Fody and re-weave the assemblies to remove/NOP/redirect the
>   WriteLine I do this to redirect the calls to in internal log and upon
>   crash or user stat requests, forward this log to our crash reporting
>   servers. etc, .....

So there are a few alternatives to consider, one of the common suggestions I've seen is to use the fully qualified reference for `WriteLine();` as such:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("woop woop");
```

I would suggest giving the above a try first.